# Exterior door threshold is too narrow

Tags: doors

I replaced an exterior door with a prehung Stanley door.   I also bought and plan to install an Anderson glass storm door.  Basically a direct replacement of the setup that was there before.

The problem is the threshold of the new door on the outside doesn't extend as far as the old one.   The old door's threshold extended out so it was a little past the face of the brick mold.

The new threshold is flush with the door frame / back side of the brick mold.  So an inch or so shorter.
[image: threshold 2]
The glass storm door mounts to the brick mold and should sit so the sweep seals on the threshold.  But there is nothing for it to sit on.

The old door was a little annoying because about an inch and a half of the threshold was unsupported and just sort of hung out in space.  But I suppose I need to extend this threshold or maybe get a 2 x something and sort of build a thick kick plate and put some kind of sill nosing on it?

Stanley also makes a threshold extension but for 36 inch door (could probably cut it down). I think it slots into those channels on the threshold. However, you are supposed to install it before installing the door.  So not sure how that will work out. Maybe it would be ok since nothing is under there currently?

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I'd go with the threshold extension. If it slides into the existing threshold then you can remove the brick mold to install it or trim the bottom of the brick mold.